# In Seam how do you create an HQL subquery restriction/alias?

Tags: hibernate, subquery, seam, alias

I'm still new to Seam/Hibernate and I am finding it hard to figure out a solution to this problem. There is a complex relationship that I need to search against and one of the problems is that it needs to be a "like" search for a concatenation of two columns on two different mapped entities. The result list is a list of PurchaseOrder entities and here is the mapping relationships: PurchaseOrder [ 1 -- 0..* ]  LineItem [ 1 -- 0..* ] BillingCode [ 1 -- 1 ] Project [ 1..* -- 1 ] Company.

Basically, a "BillingCode" is represented by "Company.companyCode || '-' || Project.projectCode" so that is how the user sees a billing code represented and that's how they will try to search for purchase orders that have at least one billing code like the search string they enter in the front end. I think I have it fine if I do an equals search, but the client would like to be able to return anything with a certain string in the representative billing code. That's where it gets tricky.

I think it would be OK of I could alias the subquery and refer to that alias, but I am aware of [a bug that is not fixed](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-892) in the version of Seam/Hibernate we are using. Currently, I am using an implementation of an EntityQuery, but have been looking into the criteria API.

```
this.setEjbql("select purchaseOrder from PurchaseOrder as purchaseOrder left join fetch purchaseOrder.vendor");

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
ValueExpression[] restrictionsArray = { 
    createValueExpression("purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderNumber = #{purchaseOrderQuery.prepRestriction(purchaseOrder.purchaseOrderNumber)}"), 
    createValueExpression("lower(concat(purchaseOrder.submitterEff.user.firstName, purchaseOrder.submitterEff.user.lastName)) like #{purchaseOrderQuery.preppedSubmitterName}"),
    createValueExpression("lower(purchaseOrder.vendor.name) like #{purchaseOrderQuery.prepRestriction(purchaseOrderQuery.vendorName)}"),
    createValueExpression("lower(concat(purchaseOrder.requestor.user.firstName, purchaseOrder.requestor.user.lastName)) like #{purchaseOrderQuery.preppedRequestorName}"),
    createValueExpression("purchaseOrder.status = #{purchaseOrder.status}"),
    createValueExpression("purchaseOrder.process = #{purchaseOrder.process}"),
    createValueExpression("(select concat(company.companyCode, project.projectCode) from BillingCode as billingCode join billingCode.project as project join project.company as company join billingCode.lineItem as lineItem where lineItem.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrder)) like #{purchaseOrderQuery.preppedBillingCode}"),
    createValueExpression("purchaseOrder.dateNeeded > #{purchaseOrderQuery.preppedDateNeededRange}")
};

this.setRestrictions(Arrays.asList(restrictionsArray));
```

Obviously, the problem occurs in this resriction `createValueExpression("(select concat(company.companyCode, project.projectCode) from BillingCode as billingCode join billingCode.project as project join project.company as company join billingCode.lineItem as lineItem where lineItem.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrder)) like #{purchaseOrderQuery.preppedBillingCode}")` because the subquery returns more than one result. I guess that could be another question is there another way to do something like an "in like" query of some kind? Where the parameter does a like search for each result in a subquery?

Comment: I'm curious, why are you writing your queries in EL?

Comment: This is just part of using Seam's EntityQuery, as far as I know. I am, for the most part, following how previous developers are implementing the search functions. The EL allows you to dynamically change inputs for search values, as far as I can see. If an EL expression resolves to null, the restriction is ignored. [Seam Application Framework](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/framework.html) <--That shows the configuration in XML, but configuring it in Java code is similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not saying that this will be a fast solution but to solve your select subquery n results issue this is how you can go around it:

instead of writing

select purchaseOrder from PurchaseOrder as purchaseOrder where (select concat(company.companyCode, project.projectCode) from BillingCode as billingCode join billingCode.project as project join project.company as company join billingCode.lineItem as lineItem where lineItem.purchaseOrder = purchaseOrder)) like #{purchaseOrderQuery.preppedBillingCode}

use

select purchaseOrder from PurchaseOrder as purchaseOrder where purchaseOrder IN (select po from PurchaseOrder po join what you need here where something like #{input})

so the restriction would be

purchaseOrder IN (subselect with like)

Comment: Thanks, that is the way I have it implemented currently and that works just fine if there is an exact match, but the customer wants a "like" search. I may just end up telling it is too difficult to do within the framework. I'm pretty sure I can do it in regular SQL, but then I lose the ease of the seam/hibernate functionality that makes the lists paginate and search correctly. I'm sure I could figure out some work-around, but I need to move on. They may just have to accept the "in" search.

Comment: Wait a minute, I didn't read that thoroughly enough. I think the bug I linked to in my post prevents me from doing that. Hibernate doesn't handle aliasing in subqueries well. However, I will try that approach some more and get back to you.

Comment: Boom! Thanks Martin! This approach works fine. Right now with just my test data it is fast, but I hope it is not super slow when they get their 30k+ records in there. If it is, I suppose they could just give up the "like" functionality.